# Sort dictionary after class attributes and today's date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class, Reminder, and dictionary, Events, and would like to sort the dictionary based on today's date.

The program should ask the user for an int input of today's date, and then print all keys in the dictionary that are relevant for this day and further.

Eg. it should not print events that have already passed.

```
   class Reminder:
    self.name = name
    self.date = date
    self.reminder = reminder
```

```
    event1 = Reminder('trip to vegas', 20130312, 'buy a suitcase')
    event2 = Reminder('to do next month', 20190401, 'get a job')
    event3 = Reminder('apply for college', 20190603, 'send in application'

    event_dict = {}
    event_dict[event1.name] = event1
    event_dict[event2.name] = event2
    event_dict[event3.name] = event3

    todays date = int(input("Input today's date!"))
```

So now when the user puts in for example the date 20190328, the program should not print event1 since it has already passed.

And as said I want event 2 and 3 to be sorted before printed, so that the next upcoming date is printed first.

It might seem unnecessary to sort 2 events but in the whole code it will be more events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple implementation:

```
class Reminder:

    def __init__(self, name, date, reminder):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.reminder = reminder 

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: '{}' - Date: '{}' - Reminder: '{}'".format(self.name,
                                                           self.date,
                                                           self.reminder)

event1 = Reminder('trip to vegas', 20130312, 'buy a suitcase')
event2 = Reminder('to do next month', 20190401, 'get a job')
event3 = Reminder('apply for college', 20190603, 'send in application')

event_dict = {}
event_dict[event1.name] = event1
event_dict[event2.name] = event2
event_dict[event3.name] = event3

todays_date = 20180101

# implementation
events_sorted = sorted(event_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[1].date)
events = [e[1] for e in events_sorted if e[1].date >= todays_date]

for e in events:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
Name: 'to do next month' - Date: '20190401' - Reminder: 'get a job'
Name: 'apply for college' - Date: '20190603' - Reminder: 'send in application'
```

Comment: You are amazing!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
class Reminder(object):
    def __init__(self, name, date, reminder):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.reminder = reminder

event1 = Reminder('trip to vegas', 20130312, 'buy a suitcase')
event2 = Reminder('to do next month', 20190401, 'get a job')
event3 = Reminder('apply for college', 20190603, 'send in application')


event_dict = {}
    event_dict[event1.date] = event1
    event_dict[event2.date] = event2
    event_dict[event3.date] = event3

todays_date = int(input("Input today's date!"))

import operator
#filter passed dates
event_dict = {k: v for k, v in event_dict.items() if k > todays_date}

#sort dictionary
sorted_events = sorted(event_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

#print results
for item in sorted_events:
    print("trip name: " , item[1].name, "| trip date: ", item[1].date, "| trip reminder: ", item[1].reminder,' \n')
```

Output:

```
trip name:  to do next month | trip date:  20190401 | trip reminder:  get a job  
trip name:  apply for college | trip date:  20190603 | trip reminder:  send in application
```